# leaflet map not working with chrome for unauthoried error

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geocode

I am trying to build map function in my website using leaflet, but the following code didn't work and when I run it there's only the zoom icon and also the copyright statement, but the map is not showing. There's this error message in chrome developer tools "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)". Could someone please help? Your help is very much appreciated!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
    crossorigin=""/>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-nMMmRyTVoLYqjP9hrbed9S+FzjZHW5gY1TWCHA5ckwXZBadntCNs8kEqAWdrb9O7rxbCaA4lKTIWjDXZxflOcA=="
    crossorigin=""></script>

    <style>
      #mapid {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
      }
    </style>

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mapid"></div>
  </body>

  <script>
    // initiate leatlet Map
    var mymap = L.map("mapid").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer(
      "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}",
      {
        attribution:
          'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: "mapbox.streets",
        accessToken: "your.mapbox.access.token"
      }
    ).addTo(mymap);
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You need a real access token: `accessToken: "your.mapbox.access.token"`